# How can i target a search bars input value and store it into a variable to use in an api fetch in javascript for flickr

Tags: javascript, variables

trying to make a geolocator with a picture search feature associated with the geo location for the user and display on the DOM. want to target the search bars input, store it into a variable, use the variable in my fetch request from a flickr.com API. so the user would type in the search bar, and click the search button and the input from which they type is in the fetch request.
declared the variable VALUE. tried to change the variable from the keydown. but wont work in the fetch request. comes up blank and I get an HTTP error.

```
const searchBar = document.querySelector('#search-Bar')
let value

searchBar.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    
value = e.target.value
    
console.log(value)

})

fetch("https://shrouded-mountain-15003.herokuapp.com/https://flickr.com/services/rest/?api_key=00a31f12afffd2cff1ceeefd8cb8f3bb&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&method=flickr.photos.search&safe_search=1&per_page=5&lat="
        +latitude+"&lon="+longitude+"&text="+value)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
const searchBar = document.querySelector(“input#search-bar”)

const value = searchBar.value
```

or if you want to get the value every time an input value changes

```
searchBar.addEventListener(“change”, (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value

    /* Whatever you want to do with the value */
})
```

Comment: tested the variable to go to the console. but its not being used in the fetch request. im not sire if i have to JSON.stringify it. it just comes up blank. and i get errors.